# Print '_' as an underline in the ticklabels of a matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a simple matlab plot and as the xticklabel I need to have some text. This works perfectly with this:

```
names={'ab_cd' 'ab_cf' 'ab_fg'};
set(gca,'xtick',[1:3],'xticklabel',names);
```

The Problem is that matlab interpretes the `_` as a subscript. I want matlab to just display the string as it is, without a subscript: `ab_cd`.

I found myself a solution by looping through the array `names` and replace the `_` with `\_`.

But I am curious if there isn't any better solution?

Can I somehow change the `'Interpreter'` to none? like it works with a title?

```
c=title('ab_cd');
set(c,'Interpreter','none');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the axis property `TickLabelInterpreter` to 'none' in a similar manner.

```
set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter','none')
```