# Matlab plot to ignore underscores?

Tags: matlab, plot, format

I have lots of file names that are labelled in the form:

```
test1_cvariable1_cvariable2_rvariable.csv
```

To load and process them all automatically I'm using the code:

```
%filename
txt = ['test1_cvariable1_cvariable2_rvariable.csv']

%step 1
RNG = [23 0 1539 8];
M = csvread(txt,23,0,RNG);
```

I'd like to then plot a graph with the corresponding title, but owing to how matlab interprets underscores "_" if I use:

```
    %plot time vs variable
plot(M(:,1),M(:,8))
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Var')
title(['Var ' txt])
```

Gives a title in the form

```
test1cvariable1cvariable2rvariable
```

with the c,c & r as subscripts (apologies idk how to do this here, ironically)

How do I get Matlab to not make the character immediately after the underscore as a subscript?

Comment: Also related: [Print '_' as an underline in the ticklabels of a matlab plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501305/print-as-an-underline-in-the-ticklabels-of-a-matlab-plot)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the Interpreter property to ‘none’ to disable MATLAB’s usual default which is ‘TeX’. This works for most plotting text functions like [title](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html), xlabel, or ylabel.

For example:

```
title('savvy_iguana', 'Interpreter', 'none')
```

Comment: Cheers pal! Works a treat.

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace `_` with `\_` (see [this mathworks answer](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94238-how-can-i-place-the-_-or-characters-in-a-text-command)). You can do it automatically using `strrep`:

```matlab
title(['Var ' strrep(txt,'_','\_')])
```